# Delete row(TR) by clicking on a href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table and i want to remove tr by clicking on a href tag. Here is the code.

```
<tr>                                
    <td data-title="ID">
            echo '<a href="" onclick="return Deleteqry('.$orderID.')";><font size="2" color="#FF0000"><i class=" fa fa-remove" title="Remove this Row"> </i></a>';

    </td>
</tr>

<script>
 function Deleteqry(id)
    { 
      if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Row?")==true)
   $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 
       return false;
    }

</script>
```

I checked other questions in SO and found        `$(this).closest('tr').remove();` but it is not working. I didn't got any error but row not deleting. I am getting alert box but row is not deleting.

Please advise what am i doing wrong.

Comment: as noted, you are losing context with the "this" keyword. It needs to be passed to your method at the time of click.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically `this` inside a normal function will point to `window` object.

```
.... onclick="return Deleteqry('.$orderID.', this)";>
```

So you have to pass it manually to the inline event handler function.

```
function Deleteqry(id,_this) { 
 if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Row?")==true)
   $(_this).closest('tr').remove(); 
   return false;
}
```

receive it, convert it as a jquery object and do your work over it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Voted up.

Comment: @CalculatingMachine - you should select this answer as "correct". Because it is.

Comment: I am not sure but getting error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , Checking it.

Comment: @CalculatingMachine Where do you get that error? I am sure that this code won't break. Can you share some details of that issue?

Comment: SyntaxError: expected expression, got ','
 

return Deleteqry(, this)

Comment: @CalculatingMachine That `'.$orderID.',` part is not required at all for us. Can you remove that from your html? That is causing the issue here as it is returning empty result.

Comment: yes, you are correct. I fixed that. just change code to pass value for orderid. Thanks for your answer.